# При вызове функции ошибка: PLS-00221: 'function_name' is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, sqlalchemy

Необходимо в скрипте вызвать пользовательскую функцию, которая возвращает строку `VARCHAR2`.

```
function f_check_source  return varchar2 is
  not_in_source varchar2(2000);
  not_in_target varchar2(2000);
  sql_stmt      varchar2(4000);
  v_out         varchar2(4000);

begin

  sql_stmt := 'select ''1'' not_in_target, ''2'' not_in_source from dual';
              
  execute immediate sql_stmt  into  not_in_target, not_in_source ;      
  
  v_out :=  'not_in_source: '||not_in_source||Chr(13)||Chr(10)||'not_in_target: '||not_in_target;
  return v_out;         

end f_check_source;
```

```
import  sqlalchemy as sa

db_source_user = 'user'
db_source_passw = 'passw'
db_source_sid = 'sid'

cstr = 'oracle://{user}:{password}@{sid}'.format(
    user=db_source_user,
    password=db_source_passw,
    sid=db_source_sid
)

engine = sa.create_engine(cstr)
connection = engine.connect()

# some code

v_out = connection.execute('begin shema.package_name.function_name(without paramemetes); end;')
# v_out = v_out.fetchone()
print(v_out)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> PLS-00221: 'function_name' is not a procedure or is undefined

Что не так делаю?

---

P.S. Гуглил, но что-то предложенные решения не помогли, ну или что-то не понял. SQLAclcheme только пробую использовать.

Comment: сначала убедитесь, что вы можете запустить этот блок в SQLPLUS используя того же пользователя (login)

Comment: С этим нет проблем, запускается и возвращает ожидаемый результат, как в IDE так и через SQLPlus. Все под тем же юзером, пакет и таблицы в схеме юзера.

Comment: какая у вас версия sqlalchemy?

Comment: SQLAlchemy 1.4.0

Comment: _С этим нет проблем, запускается и возвращает ожидаемый результат, как в IDE так и через SQLPlus_, не обманывайте, так, как вы показали в вопросе, работать нигде не будет. Покажите пожалуйста на [фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bda5e14edbd1acf97f678b972a0f4898), как вы всё же функцию вызываете.

Comment: Сори, действительно затупил. На начальном этапе функция это была процедурой и  в скрипте сохранился старый способ вызова.

v_out = connection.execute('select shema.package_name.function_name from dual').fetchall()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была ошибка в способе обращения к функции:

```
import  sqlalchemy as sa

db_source_user = 'user'
db_source_passw = 'passw'
db_source_sid = 'sid'

cstr = 'oracle://{user}:{password}@{sid}'.format(
    user=db_source_user,
    password=db_source_passw,
    sid=db_source_sid
)

engine = sa.create_engine(cstr)
connection = engine.connect()

# some code

v_out = connection.execute('select shema.package_name.function_name from dual;').fetchone()
v_out = v_out._data[0]
print(v_out)
```

P.S. спасибо 0xdb  за то. что обратил внимание.

Но у этого способа есть нюанс. DML операции нельзя вызывать из DDL, соответственно если вызываемая функция исполняет команду DML, в execute() нам нужно использовать анонимный блок.  И вот тут вопрос как вернуть из функции с DML значение.
При попытке обращаться к функции:

```
connection.execute(declare x number; begin x :=  shema.package_name.function_name; end;).fetchone()
```

> {ResourceClosedError}This result object does not return rows. It has
> been closed automatically.

Переписал в процедуру, которая на выходе дает SYS_REFCIRSOR/[фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c662afe243e85ee5a4f778ed1a9ddcf)

```
connection.execute('declare res sys_refcursor; begin shema.package_name.procedure_name(res); end;').fetchone()
```

Та же ошибка. Пока не победил.

Comment: А что вы делаете? Дал вам развёрнутый ответ, а он повидимому не помог. И ошибка говорит сама за себя, а вы всё равно пытаетесь фетчем что-то получить. Верните же наконец результат в переменную.

Comment: Как раз таки и помог. execute(select package_name.function_name from dual; ) все успешно возвращает.  Но есть момент, этот способ не подходит для функций в которых используются DML команды. А с bind переменными у меня пока возникают сложности, v_out = connection.execute('begin :res := package_name.function_name; end;', res = None), возвращает ссылку на курсор (<sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.LegacyCursorResult object at 0x000001D753DC6580>),  при фетче получаю "This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.". Пока нашел обходное решение, но хочу разобраться с этим.

Comment: Если ответ помог, то отметьте его как принятый. А этот "ответ" (ответом он не является) преобразуйте в новый вопрос, так на ответ вы не получите ответа. Вам надо воспользоваться [outparam](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.outparam), чтобы получить результат выполнения функции. Анонимный блок не возвращает строки данных, про это и говорится в ошибке, фетч тут не нужен.

Answer (score 5):

Функции в PL/SQL не могут возвращать результат в "никуда", что имеет  место в других ЯП.

Вот так работать не будет:

```
create package pack is function foo return int;
end;
/
create package body pack is  
    function foo return int is begin return 0; end;
end;
/
begin pack.foo; end;
/
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'FOO' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

Функция должна быть вызвана внутри выражения, которое может принять её результат.
Об этом и сообщает компилятор в сообщении об ошибке - он пытается найти процедуру, потому что её вызов это законченое выражение.

Или просто в SQL запросе:

```sql
select pack.foo res from dual
/

     RES
--------
       0
```

Или с переменной связывания в анонимном блоке:

```sql
var res number
begin :res := pack.foo; end;
/
print res

     RES
--------
       0
```